modular properties of macmahon function?
How does the MacMahon function for counting plane partitions
$M(q) = \frac{1}{(1-q^n)^n}$
behave under modular transformations?
For instance for $q= e^{2 \pi i \tau}$ where $\tau \rightarrow -1/\tau$.

conformal-field-theory? string-theory??

According to https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.15145 it is not related to a weakly modular form.  Is that what you wanted to know?

Do you want a product sign somewhere?
